# Can someone explain this Java scoping mystery?

Tags: java, scope

A peer at work has extended LinkedHashMap, and overridden `removeEldestEntry` similar to:

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map.Entry;

public class CompileTest {
    static class MyMap<K, V> extends LinkedHashMap<K, V> {
        protected boolean removeEldestEntry(Entry<K, V> eldest) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Notice the parameter class is `Entry`, not `Map.Entry`.
Eclipse generated the method signature. IntelliJ shows an error complains that `Entry` has private access in `java.util.LinkedHashMap`, and prefers `Map.Entry`. But it still compiles either way.

I wrote a smaller example to experiment:

```
public class CompileTest {

    static class A{
        public class Inner {
        }

        public void doStuff(Inner a){}
    }

    static class B extends A{
        private class Inner {
        }
    }

    static class C extends B {
        public void doStuff(Inner a) { }
    }
}
```

Now IntelliJ does not show an error, but the class fails to compile. Here are 2 situations that seem the same, where both the IDE and the compiler seem to alternate behaviors and also never agree with each other.

Can someone explain this?

Comment: the compiler is always the **correct** reference ... also your example isn't doing the same thing as `Entry` vs `Map.Entry` which is an inner class of `LinkedList` making `Entry` and inner class of `Map`

Comment: Is there a difference in static imports between the two examples?

Comment: They seem the same? Where is the `import` statement in your test case? Imports effectively establish aliases that disambiguate which fully-qualified-name a given unqualified name references. Your test case doesn't have that.

Comment: +1 to Jarrod. Your example does not reflect the scoping issue that you originally stated in your question. For one, your inner class definitions are a level too deep, and you are also declaring the Inner class as private in class B, effectively hiding it from class C. Thats the source of your compilation error.

Comment: The bug is in Eclipse by the way. The code it generates is simply wrong. HashMap.Entry gets precedence over Map.Entry with the Eclipse generated code.

Comment: @M Platvoet. But it compiles. and as I said in another comment, using the @Override annotation does not produce an error upon compiling, indicating that the appropriate method was overriden.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the Java Language Specification - [8.5 Member Type Declarations](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/classes.html#8.5)

> If the class declares a member type
>   with a certain name, then the
>   declaration of that type is said to
>   hide any and all accessible
>   declarations of member types with the
>   same name in superclasses and
>   superinterfaces of the class.
>
> A class inherits from its direct
>   superclass and direct superinterfaces
>   all the non-private member types of
>   the superclass and superinterfaces
>   that are both accessible to code in
>   the class and not hidden by a
>   declaration in the class.

We can deduce that:

`B.Inner` hides `A.Inner`. `B` does not inherit `A.Inner`. `A.Inner` is not a member(8.2) type of `B`. `C` cannot inherit `A.Inner` from `B`. C cannot inherit `B.Inner` from `B` because it's private.

Therefore `C` does not have a member type `Inner`. Assume there is no other `Inner` type in C's enclosing scopes (outer class; compilation unit; package), then type name `Inner` cannot be resolved.

`javac` tries to report a more detailed error, but that's only a guess at your intention. An even better error message probably should include all the above explanations.

In the 1st example about `Entry`, the import statement declares `Entry` in the entire compilation unit scope(i.e. the java file), therefore `Entry` is resolved to be `Map.Entry`

IntelliJ 10.5 doesn't complain about the 1st example; apparently the bug has been fixed. It is still wrong on the 2nd example.

There is something funny about `private`. Why does the spec explicitly exclude `private` members while it already requires members be "accessible"? Actually `B.Inner` is accessible in the entire body of `CompileTest` (6.6.1), including `C`. `C` can have a `doStuff(B.Inner)` and it will compile.

That's probably why IntelliJ screws up on the 2nd example; it thinks that `B.Inner` is accessible to `C`, therefore `C` inherits `B.Inner`. It overlooked the extra exclusion clause of `private` members in inheritance.

This reveals 2 conflicting views on the scope of a `private` declaration. View #1 wants the scope to be the immediate enclosing class, view #2 wants it to be the top level enclosing class. #2 is less known by programmers, they'd be surprised to learn that `C` can access `B.Inner`. #2 can be justified in the following way: they are all in the same file anyway, so there's no need for encapsulation, we aren't protecting anyone by prohibiting the access; allowing access is more convenient in most use cases.

View #2 probably also argued that `C` should inherit `B.Inner` - what could go wrong? Interestingly #2 wins on the general access control rule, but lost on the inheritance rule.

The spec is really really messy, fortunately we usually don't run into these complicated situations. It is rather the fault of `LinkedHashMap` and `HashMap` that repurpose a public name for private use.

Answer (score 1):

That is because `Entry` and `Map.Entry` are two different classes. The first has default scope and is defined in [HashMap](http://kickjava.com/src/java/util/HashMap.java.htm), the latter is a [public interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Map.Entry.html). So you are using a private parameter in a method with a broader scope. This does compile but probably isn't your intention.

Comment: Yes, and A.Inner and B.Inner are 2 different classes. Yet one compiles and the other doesn't. What is the difference between the 2 situations? Also, IntelliJ disagrees with the compiler on both counts. I guess I just discovered 2 IntelliJ bugs? or something more subtle? That's the mystery.

Comment: Like I said, it's scoping. Since Entry has default access you actually can only call this method from within this class or any of it's inheritors. But classes in the same package, which you grant access by defining your method 'protected', actually can't call this method since they can't access the parameter. So it's legal to compile this but IntelliJ complains because this is useless.

Comment: Using the @override annotation indicates it does, in fact, override the desired method. It is not useless, and IntelliJ has no need to complain (as far as I can see).

Answer (score 0):

You just need to specify which 'Inner' you are referencing. The IDE is just a tool to assist you; the compiler is always the definitive reference.

```
...
static class C extends B {

    public void doStuff(A.Inner a) {
    }
}
...
```

To further clarify, you can obtain the same 'subtle/strange' behaviour using standard variables. A private definition is shadowing a public definition.

```
public class CompileTest {

    static class A {

        public static Object foo;

    }

    static class B extends A {

        private static Object foo;

    }

    static class C extends B {

        public void doStuff() {
            foo = new Object(); // Will not compile - 'foo' is not visible
            A.foo = new Object(); // Works
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I know how to make it work. I am asking about a subtle and strange behavior. My question asks "can someone explain this?". Not "how do I change it to make it work?"

Comment: I don't see anything subtle or strange here.

Comment: It's strange that a world class IDE's static code analysis is wrong twice.

Comment: world class... heh :P such amusing statements are these personal opinions.

Comment: @Tim Bender According to Tiobe and similar, Java is one of the top 1 or 2 most common languages. IntelliJ is in the top 2 or 3 Java SE/EE (and Scala/Clojure) IDEs available (along with Eclipse and Netbeans). I don't think there is anything very personal or amusing about that. Is there a "Practical Philosophy of Java IDE's" stackexchange we can continue this conversation at?